# Pass object and key into an generic component in Angular: T[K]

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working with Angular and Typescript version 4.4.4. I'm trying to create a
generic component in which I set obj (data object) and key (properties).

My text component is like as below (simplified):

```
// text.component.ts
class TextComponent<T, K extends Extract<keyof T, string>> {

  @Input()
  obj : T;

  @Input()
  key: K;

  constructor(){}

  // challenge: we cannot change the signature of this function, simulation purpose 
  currency(cost: string | number) {
    console.log('func::currency', cost);
  }

  test(){
      this.currency(this.obj[this.key]);
  }
}

// text.component.html (template)
// currency is an PipeTranform build-in Angular
//{{ obj[key] | currency:'US' }}
```

Unfornatetely, I'm stuck with this error and I have no idea to overcome this.

```
Argument of type 'T[K]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | number'.
  Type 'T[Extract<keyof T, string>]' is not assignable to type 'string | number'.
    Type 'T[string]' is not assignable to type 'string | number'.
      Type 'T[string]' is not assignable to type 'number'.
        Type 'T[Extract<keyof T, string>]' is not assignable to type 'number'.
          Type 'T[K]' is not assignable to type 'number'.
            Type 'T[Extract<keyof T, string>]' is not assignable to type 'number'.
              Type 'T[string]' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

Of course, I could use `this.currency(this.obj[this.key] as any);`, but I'm don't want to do that.

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictPropertyInitialization=false&ts=3.8.3#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGrACYQPYEEDO+EY+yA3gLABQyymAXMvmFKAOYDc1tUAruMAC2ERs1YhO3ZBjiRRLdlxrIE2ZoxC9BAI2hKAvtWqqQzZADdMOAkTCN0WPIWKkAvOSkNkAIgCM3gBopPgFhRm8ABgAmemjYqMCpGTkfKOjfAFpfTIiAVkTlVXVkbIA6AE5yoKpDKmMAGzhCZAAVCAAPMABhbEEAB2wQCHAAHhaA5ABpZA7IEAxSAFFOqEQwEYBrCABPbBhWibF2AD5jjzrlbG0AK2RGFqVaLe3GSaUpEzFeBDBsKAAKK7Xe4TZ6vACUlGUtDAAAtgPhSkDkO4gY9aMg4QjSs8UchnujalIAPTElSwuD1erDNgiZAAdxQCDgIBA2DA5JZtMxsJQ+GAbBAsl4UBQex5COQMH4P2Agw+ItFIAQ23+RTsTAUEmQAB9kJodNBwecMSpBvhsNTSvVsGx-gByaXK+j0BCK4Yq+0TdXgwlGZSQZj-SFSU1YxFuqBKlX-cNIm4AbTjzwAur6pETlH1xGBg1DTZ9LRBrbaHU6EC7s6AwF6JYigUn4YjU+nlLVM6TMbNSqp+oNhmBSrCwIJ6tRO5Ho9s6KQAArAPoQFqrEAwP6CKVQXrIbS8YD1DAZUDIXASXiNKDj4lkMjkW8N1O6lTu5Uve0AVQAyvbkPp9L-MyvLtmGMc0OV7AYhnAPEhnpVpZh6PsoNzSxHBsYgJntdV7VbCD+3AUpA1zXDekggdSircBgw4IA)

Answer (score 1):

How about this...

```
interface VideoAssets extends Record<string, string|number> {
  id: string;
  runtime: string;
  date: string;
  cost: number;
}

const videoAsset: VideoAssets = {
  id: "1",
  runtime: "02:02:02",
  date: "2021-11-05",
  cost: 11.99,
}

class TextComponent<T extends Record<string, string|number>, K extends Extract<keyof T, string>> {

  obj : T;
  key: K;

  constructor(obj: T, key: K){
    this.obj = obj;
    this.key = key;
  }

  // challenge: we cannot change the signature of this function
  currency(cost: string | number) {
    console.log('func::currency', cost);
  }

  test(){
      this.currency(this.obj[this.key]);
  }

  print(){
    console.log('func::print', this.obj[this.key]);
  }
}

// text.component.html
// currency is PipeTranform from build-in Angular
//{{ {{ obj[key] | currency:'US' }} }}


// test
const component = new TextComponent(videoAsset, 'cost');
component.test();
component.print();
```

[Playground Demo](https://tsplay.dev/mAvn4W)

Comment: Thank Nalin, of course, your solution works flawless. Futhermore, I'd like to add that I tried TextComponent<T extends {[P in keyof T]: T[P]} that also works. Now I'm wondering what's the difference between  {[P in keyof T]: T[P]} versus Record<string, string|number>?

Comment: The one that you have tried is [Indexed-Access Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html), and surely is more open than the `Record` type that we have used above. You can read about [Record Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type).